# maximization and optimization with constraints

Tags: optimization, economics

maximize the following equation

$$\max \log\big(z-T(z)\big) - z/w$$

subject to

$$T(z) = 0, \quad\quad\quad\; \quad\text{ if } z\leqslant k,$$

$$T(z) = m(z-k), \quad\text{ if } z>k.$$

Comment: Make a case decison,:  **1)** For $z\leq k$ the objective function is $\log(z)-z/w$. **2)** For $z>k$ the objective function is $\log(z-m(z-k))-z/w$. Differentiate in both cases and set the derivatives equal to zero. And so on ...

Comment: If the first case the optimal value is $z^*=w$  and in the second case $z^*=w-mk$